# np.piecewise returning constant value

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, which store values for a step function in the sense that starting at a certain `x` location, `y` has a certain value.
In my example below, the function should be zero from 0 to 10, 1 from 10 to 20 and so on.

Now, I would like to interpolate so that I can plot it. The result should be an array with 10 times 0, followed by 10 times 1, etc. However, what I get is a constant value at the last value. What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# points for the step function
x = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
y = np.arange(len(x))
# points to evaluate at
x2 = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
# boolean matrix where to evaluate which function
tf = [((x2 >= z[0]) & (x2 < z[1])) for z in np.c_[x,np.append(x, 999999999)[1:]]]
# functions to evaluate at the corresponding regions
fs = [lambda x: n for n in y]
y2 = np.piecewise(x2, tf, fs)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)   # this should be a straight line --> CORRECT
ax.plot(x2, y2) # this should look like stairs --> NOT CORRECT, CONSTANT = 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic rookie error related to how python handles namespaces, and nothing to do with your numpy-fu. First the fix: change the assignment of `fs` to

```
fs = [lambda x, n=n: n for n in y]
```

Notice the `n=n` in the argument list. This is a common hack to bind the name `n` in the `lambda` to a fixed value. Default parameters are bound at the time the function is defined. If you don't bind to a parameter name, your `lambda` uses normal LEGB lookup order. Since `n` is not defined locally or in an enclosing scope, it uses the global value *at the time you call the function*. At that point, `n` is the last value of the loop: `y[-1]`.